# Find the DVD-ROM path in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, path, data-cd

I do not know the path of my DVD-ROM and also my external hard drive to mount them in FreeBSD using the `mount` command.
What command should I use to find their path?

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed from that drive, then generally there will be an entry in fstab.  Try
`cat /etc/fstab` which should list all of the file systems available to the OS.  Look for a line that says something like...

```
/dev/acd0     /cdrom       cd9660   ro,noauto 0 0
```

If that line is present then all you need to do is type `mount /cdrom` and then `cd /cdrom` to start browsing the disc.

Use `dmesg | more` to walk through the device discovery as the operating system boots up.  For instance, in the VM I'm running mine is listed as:

```
Hard Drive: ad0
DVDROM: acd0
Hard Drive: ad2
```

What you're going to be looking for in dmesg is something like:

```
<deviceid0>: xxxxxxMB <manufacturer of HD> at usbX ....
```

That will be the location of the device, if the device already has contents on it, then you need to know how it was formated.  If the disk is formatted for use with Windows, as an example, you'll want to do something along these lines:

```
mkdir /usbhd
mount -t msdosfs <deviceid> /usbhd
```

And then you can access it via:

```
cd /usbhd
```